# How to monitor particular command or add extra functions to it?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am attempting to implement mobile push notifications (utilizing the Docker ntfy service) for scenarios such as automatic system updates and Timeshift snapshot creation.

None of these commands are scheduled regularly in my case; hence, Crontab is not a viable option (just a quick disclaimer). My objective is to receive notifications about events like Timeshift preparing a snapshot. At the moment the task is successfully completed, a push notification should be sent. In the event of failure, I also want to be notified.

My local Docker ntfy service is functioning seamlessly. However, I am interested in incorporating additional commands before and after the Timeshift operation. I have considered using aliases, but they must have the same name, which I believe is not feasible.

Modifying the command might result in problems, as illustrated  [in bellow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56213537/how-to-modify-standard-linux-commands).

Any suggestions on how to address such a scenario?

Expected outcome:

1. The system initiates the Timeshift process.
2. A notification is pushed with relevant comments.
3. The snapshot is successfully created.
4. Another push command is sent upon completion.

What is importand - I'd like to keep all functionallity delivered with particular command. So in case of Timeshift  which comes wit variety of options and flags they should stay in place.

Comment: 1. What does starting the Timeshift process involve? I assume running the `sudo timeshift` command. Have you tried just writing a simple shell script that contains a line for each of those 4 steps? 2. If not, is the filename and path constant?

Comment: 1) In my case that's mostly :  sudo timeshift --create -m 'comment'. No I haven't because my goal is to run a such scenario dinamically whenever command will be used by any user. 2) On particualr system - it is, but I'd like to implement for more devices..

Comment: You might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4824637/10477326

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `timeshift` command in a `bash` script, and invoke that script. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# set up environment (PATH, ...)
#
notify-send timeshift "Timeshift starting"
timeshift ...
err=$?
if [[ 0 -ne $err ]] ; then
  printf -v msg "failed with error code %d" $err
else
  msg="succeeded"
fi
notify-send timeshift "Timeshift $msg"
```

Change all the configurations, `.desktop` files, scripts, etc. where you invoke `timeshift` to call the script instead.

OR

You could play games with `$PATH` - Put your `timeshift` script (for this to work, you have to call itv`timeshift`) in a directory that's earlier in your `$PATH` than the real `timeshift`; invoke the real `timeshift` in your script using the absolute path (`/usr/bin/timeshift`); make the `$PATH` changes in `~/.profile` so they'll be in effect when automatic things start.⁸

Comment: thank you for your input! Yest, partially it's way I'd like to handle that. And yours script looks prommising. But main question here is how to monitor a moment when system is going to run that specific command ( let's stick to timeshift as we already using that example). Timeshift might be fired up during system updating, or installing a new packages.. Then how to invoke your script in cases like that? That's my main problem ;)

Comment: @zawier Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

@waltinator I have modified your code ending with  bellow result:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -d "TIMESHIFT Creating snapshot.. " local_ip:port/Ubuntu

if [ -n "$SUDO_PASSWORD" ]; then
    result=$(echo "$SUDO_PASSWORD" | sudo -S /usr/bin/timeshift $@)
    err=$?
    
    if [[ 0 -ne $err ]] ; then
        curl -d "TIMESHIFT - ERR: $result"  local_ip:port/Ubuntu
    else
        curl -d "TIMESHIFT - snapshot created!" local_ip:port/Ubuntu
    fi
    
else
    curl -d "TIMESHIFT SUDO_PASSWORD not exists!!! " local_ip:port/Ubuntu
fi
```

File name in my case is *timeshift_ntfy.sh.*
In case when I run it directly from bash it works just great! To this moment I'm more than happy.

But here I'm stucked.

> make the $PATH changes in ~/.profile so they'll be in effect when
> automatic things start

I've tried adding to ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc file  following line:

```
export PATH="/home/zawier/Skrypty/timeshift_ntfy:/home/zawier/Skrypty/timeshift:$PATH"
```

I have thought it's correct way, but I was wrong while saw that output was from orginal timeshift. Of course I have done :

```
source ~/.profile
source ~/.bashrc
```

Unfortunatelly with no luck :( What I'm doing here incorrectly?